# Brushes Drawing Perpendicular Lines?

Tags: sculpting

All sculpting brushes draw two straight lines and out come two lines, each with an accompnaying perpendicular line. Any idea what's going on here? [image]

Edit: I should also mention that it only happens in this singular location. No where else really. So I don't think it could be an issue with the axis.

Comment: The brush used in the pic is the masking brush which is a sculpting brush. All sculpting brushes have this same behavior though.I used that because it would leave a more visible mark than changing the mesh would have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly suspect symmetry across x or y axis is engaged Martin! Many fun parameters located at bottom of 'Tools' tab of toolbox (shortcut T, or can be pulled out from tiny "+" at left edge of main 3d viewport).  :-)

Comment: This was it. Thought I checked for this but I was wrong.